# Please correct my line of thoughts about this question on States of Matter because I seem to be missing out on something major

Tags: atoms, molecules, states-of-matter

Ok So please forgive me for my weird doubts and obviously stupid doubt but we (a grade 10 student) study that solid, liquid, gas is sometimes defined according to the distance between the molecules and atoms i.e. really close, far, far away. According to me this definition seems a bit incomplete, I mean if I get a microscope powerful enough (and we observe molecules of a solid), even the molecules of solid will be far enough so if hypothetically there is an observer perceiving things at that magnification, that substance would be gaseous for them. So is my line of thoughts correct or is there something big that I am missing out on. Also I know that energy of molecules is also a deciding factor for State of Matter but hypothetically I think at that magnified world level the energy of that particle of a solid(solid at normal sight i.e. for us) would be what I perceive for gas at my normal sight. (Please tell me if I wasn't clear explaining Question)

Comment: What does your teacher say about this, and if you don't believe that explanation, why not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter

Comment: @DavidWhite My teacher doesn't answer my doubts, he just changes the topic and goes to something else that is why I was searching for a Q&A site and I came to this place when I searched something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this understanding may be a good rule of thumb, it’s not universally true: ice floats in water, so clearly the atoms in solid ice are farther apart than the atoms in liquid water.

A more advanced picture is the **Landau theory**. In this framework, phases of matter are defined by their *symmetries*. For example, a solid crystal is periodic, so all lattice sites look the same. If I shift the crystal by one period of the lattice, I’m looking at the same thing. It has a *discrete* translational symmetry.

A liquid, on the other hand, is more of a jumble of particles. If I shift a liquid by *any* distance, I see the same thing. This is a *continuous* translational symmetry.

Somewhere between liquid and solid phases, our continuous symmetry breaks down into a discrete one. This notion of *broken symmetry* is how Landau defined a phase transition.

Comment: There are also topologically ordered phases of matter, which are not captured by the Landau symmetry breaking picture. For example, two different fractional quantum Hall phases with different filling fractions have the same symmetries, but may have different electromagnetic response, ground state degeneracy, or quasiparticle statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Solid, liquid and gas are relative terms. According to your analogy,  if **"we observe solid at a magnified level , then that should appear as a gas"**. Well yes , but actually no.

If (for that magnified frame of reference)  there exists any  other state of matter(which does not exist in our frame) having molecular distances less than that of solid , then Yes . That solid (in our frame) would  be called gas in that reference frame.

But matter doesn't exists depending upon reference frames (does it?).

So even if you are observing solid molecules separated by a great distance (in that magnified reference frame) , it would still be called solid since there would exist liquid and gas in that  same magnified frame having molecular distances far greater than that of the solid.